# Close SqlConnection in the Finally when using "Using"

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I want to close the SqlConnection in the Finally since the using not really close it and the connection pool gets full. but I don't realize what's the right way to fo that since the conn object isn't reachable any more in the finally section.

```
try 
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_dbconnstr)) 
    {
        //...
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //...
}
finally 
{
    conn.Close //?!?!?!?!???
}
```

Comment: You have some other problem. `using` is internally implemented as a `try`/`finally` pair, with Dispose being called in the `finally` block. And for `SqlConnection`, `Close` and `Dispose` are interchangable.

Comment: As mentioned as an answer, I would suggest you to check the same thing about DataReaders : the way you are closing Connection is ok.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed the point that the complete Using block is inside a try{ } block. I misread this because bracket are indented a strange way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_dbconnstr)) 
{
    //code
}
```

is expaded to:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_dbconnstr);
try
{
    //code
}
finally
{
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

So you should handle errors but you can forget about closing connection.

Comment: (A small nitpick: Your expansion is incorrect. If the constructor throws then the attempt to call `Dispose` in the `finally` block will also throw a `NullReferenceException` and hide the real error. The compiler actually puts the assignment outside the `try` block, and then performs a null check in the `finally` block too, before calling `Dispose`.)

Comment: @LukeH NullReferenceException will not be thrown since the assignment is before the try lock. So if the constructor fails execution does not get into the try..finally block.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to close `conn` in the `finally` block. The `using` block will handle closing the connection for you. (In fact, you probably don't need the `try...finally` at all in this case, unless you have other resources that need dealing with in the `finally`.)

The `using` block will translate to something like this:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(/*...*/);
try
{
    // ...
}
finally
{
    if (conn != null)
        ((IDisposable)conn).Dispose();
}
```

The `Dispose` method of the `SqlConnection` object will be called in the `finally` block, and the `Dispose` method goes on to call `Close` for you.

Comment: Always initialize inside the try block.

Comment: @Claus: I'm only explaining what's generated by the compiler, and that performs the assignment immediately *before* the `try` block, exactly as I've shown. You should check your facts before downvoting!

Answer (score 2):

Exiting a using block calls `.Dispose()` on the object, for a `SqlConnection` will close the connection and any open resources.

So the `try`, `finally` block is not needed.

Comment: that is not correct. try block is needed if the system wants to do something with error. For example, logging the exception message which sometimes very useful during debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the following using statement:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_dbconnstr)) 
{

}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
SqlConnection conn;
try
{
    //`using` scope operations are executed here
    conn = new SqlConnection(_dbconnstr));

}
catch
{
    //exceptions are bubbled
    throw;
}
finally
{
    //Dispose is always called
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Wrong. It's equiviliant to doing: var conn = new SqlConnection(_dbconnstr); { ... } conn.Dispose(); It have nothing to do with try/catch. {} represents a scope in C#.

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen: So that would mean pretty much _every_ answer to this question is _wrong_ by you reasoning? Wrong. It _does_ have _everything_ to do with (at least) `try / finally`.

Comment: No, just about half of them. (Also note the comment was updated)

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen: Your first comment doesn't make sense - just newing up an instance and expecting to be able to reach the `Dispose` call _is not_ how `using` works: `using` guarantees `Dispose` will be called, and this happens within a `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding Dispose() method of connection object will close the Connection. You don't need to call Connection.Close explicitly.

Comment: Dispose calls .Close() internally. The difference is you can't reopen it when it's disposed.

Comment: thats true. I didn't thought about that. But if we are using "using" keyword, then no point in calling Connection.Close() right?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are closing the connection with `Using` is Ok. Perhaps you might have forgotten to close some DataReaders instead ?