# Declare a resource outside the using statement

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, sqlconnection, using-statement

I have a question about C# `using` statement. According to the docs, it is a best practice to both declare and initialize the resource (for instance, a `SqlConnection` object) inside the using statement. My question is: if I'll only declare the object outside the using scope (and initialize it as part of the using statement), is it completely equal to declaring it as part of the `using` statement? My use case is that I need to use an `SqlConnection` object outside the using scope. (I would like to call `SqlConnection.ClearPool` on it, in case I get some specific exception.

Comment: the concept of using to adding finally under the hood so some thing like using(var x = new Instance){ what evey } is equal to try{ var x=new Instance } finally{x.Dispose} https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563886/close-sqlconnection-in-the-finally-when-using-using

Comment: Declaring the variable before the using statement and then initializing the variable in the using statement is not a concern. The scope of the using statement is to dispose that variable when you exit the using block. But then you cannot use that variable anymore without reinitializing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both scenarios are equivalent. But when you declare a variable outside the scope of the *using statement*, the variable will get disposed after the completion of the *using statement*'s scope but still remain in scope. Accidental use of the variable after the *using statement*'s scope may lead to exception to be thrown. This is considered to be bad practice and is avoided. I have never had reason to declare the variable before the using statement.